# caller object method to destroy another object

Tags: java

If I create objects of type `lion`, and objects of type `prey`, I want to do:

```
lion.eat(prey)
```

during which

```
lion.energy=energy+10,as an example.
prey=null
```

But I also want to destroy the prey completely from the logical ecosystem.

I know about garbage collector and all that, and all the things you people say about garbage collector will destroy the object later as soon as nothing points to it.

But I am implementing a genetic algorithm with millions of lion and deer instances in a virtual ecosystem. Now how do I eliminate the dead animals?

Please no geeky jokes, I'm tired of always stumbling on the same answers of garbage collectors and object murder, I want a description of a solution to logically dereference the prey object from a lion method.

```
public class prey
{
  int energy=10;
}

public class lion
{
  int energy=0;

  public void eat(prey aDeer)
  {
    this.energy=aDeer.energy+this.energy; ///acumulate energy values from prey
    aDeer=null;//destroys the object from ecosystem, which seems impossible to do in java
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do manual memory management in Java. If it's such a concern that not too many are allocated at once, why not cache for reuse?

Answer (score 1):

You already have millions of prey, and you're probably storing them in a collection; for example, an `ArrayList`.  It is quite simple to remove an item from an `ArrayList`; call its `.remove()` function.

Comment: calling remove on ArrayList with millions entries is simple, but not efficient. But for millions entries using set would not be so much better (it would be much faster, but more memory intensive, but it could still be acceptable. But this is more about efficiently storing and manipulating entities and not about how to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been mentioned you cannot perform explicit memory management in Java; all you can do is ensure that no reference keeps dead objects alive (pun intended!) and let the garbage collector do its job. Note that this is likely to be more efficient than explicit memory management specifically in the case of a high number of small objects being destroyed.

If the overall size of your population changes much more slowly than the rate at which its members are born and die you might indeed,as @veer suggested, consider keeping a pool of animals and rather than create new objects extract them from your pool when they are born and return them there when they die.

Answer (score 0):

If object creation and destruction is bottleneck (find out by profiling, not guessing), you could put all animals in array (or array list to allow growing, if max population is not known), in each animal store its current index, and when killing animal, swap it with last alive animal and decrease counter of live animals. In fewer words, make pool of animals as was previously suggested.
If only few animals are kept to next generation, consider 2 arrays and just walk through previous and process living into new generation and switch those arrays.

But for making it useful, you would need to have all animals (in given array) to be structurally same, so what was once deer can be next time rabbit.
So either have just class Animal, or one array per species.

PS. Don't try to find way to manually destroy object, either find way to avoid creating and destroying objects (esp. if generation sizes does not change much, so everyone will be needed again) or rely on GC.